# Matplotlib graphing distribution with two colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, probability

The goal here is to color value above a certain threshold into one color and values below this threshold into another color. The code below tries to just separate it into two histographs but it only looks balanced if the threshold is at 50%. I'm assuming I must play around with the discreetlevel variable.

`finalutilityrange` is some vector with a bunch of values(you must generate it to test the code), which I am trying to graph. The value `deter` is the value that determines whether they will be blue or red. `discreetlevel` is just the amount of bins I would want.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

discreetlevel = 10
deter = 2

for x in range(0,len(finalutilityrange)):
    if finalutilityrange[x-1]>=deter:
        piraterange.append(finalutilityrange[x-1])
    else:
        nonpiraterange.append(finalutilityrange[x-1])

plt.hist(piraterange,bins=discreetlevel,normed=False,cumulative=False,color = 'b')
plt.hist(nonpiraterange,bins=discreetlevel),normed=False,cumulative=False,color = 'r')
plt.title("Histogram")
plt.xlabel("Utlity")
plt.ylabel("Probability")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Not part of your question, but your for-loop is implemented wrong. It is your good fortune that Python interprets `finalutilityrange[-1]` instead of raising an error.

Comment: Thanks for the correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is a bit more complex than @user2699's. I am just presenting it for completeness. You have full control over the patch objects that `hist` returns, so if you can ensure that the threshold you are using is exactly on a bin edge, it is easy to change to color of selected patches. You can do this because `hist` can accept a sequence of bin edges as the `bins` parameter.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

# Make sample data
finalutilityrange = np.random.randn(100)
discreetlevel = 10
deter = 0.2

# Manually create `discreetlevel` bins anchored to  `deter`
binsAbove = round(discreetlevel * np.count_nonzero(finalutilityrange > deter) / finalutilityrange.size)
binsBelow = discreetlevel - binsAbove
binwidth = max((finalutilityrange.max() - deter) / binsAbove,
               (deter - finalutilityrange.min()) / binsBelow)
bins = np.concatenate([
           np.arange(deter - binsBelow * binwidth, deter, binwidth),
           np.arange(deter, deter + (binsAbove + 0.5) * binwidth, binwidth)
])

# Use the bins to make a single histogram
h, bins, patches = plt.hist(finalutilityrange, bins, color='b')

# Change the appropriate patches to red
plt.setp([p for p, b in zip(patches, bins) if b >= deter], color='r')
```

The result is a homogenous histogram with bins of different colors:

[image]

The bins may be a tad wider than if you did not anchor to `deter`. Either the first or last bin will generally go a little past the edge of the data.

Comment: @Mad_Physicist Slightly confused, what is x?

Comment: @Dio. Thanks for the catch. `x` is a variable I had in the workspace I was testing in that I forgot to change to `finalutilityrange`. Fixed now.

Comment: Also updated that list comprehension in the end. Note that `setp` has a bit of a problem with arbitrary iterables that are not lists, which was fixed but may not yet be in the official 1.5 releases yet.

Comment: Then how to add legend to this two types of data with different colors?

Comment: @rosefun. I'd recommend searching and asking a new question if you can't find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer doesn't address your code since it isn't self-contained, but for what you're trying to do the default histogram should work (assuming numpy/pyplot is loaded)

```
x = randn(100)
idx = x < 0.2 # Threshold to separate values
hist([x[idx], x[~idx]], color=['b', 'r'])
```

Explanation:

1. first line just generates some random data to test,
2. creates an index for where the data is below some threshold, this can be negated with ~ to find where it's above the threshold
3. Last line plots the histogram.  The command takes a list of separate groups to plot, which doesn't make a big difference here but if `normed=True` it will

There's more the hist plot can do, so look over the documentation before you accidentally implement it yourself.

Comment: @user2699 Thanks that works! Question: what exactly is the ~ doing? 

And for some reason there is a split in the graph between the colors, any idea why? A bar is missing right between the red and blue colors...

Comment: It's because your split threshold is not aligned to the bins of one or both of the histograms.

Comment: @Dio, the `~` negates `idx`, so it finds where values are above the threshold.  The bar issue  could also be the way it's displayed, each group gets a space for each bin, even if the value is 0.  You can change that behavior with the option `histype`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as above do:

```
x = np.random.randn(100)
threshold_x = 0.2 # Threshold to separate values

x_lower, x_upper = (
    [_ for _ in x if _ < threshold_x], 
    [_ for _ in x if _ >= threshold_x]
)

hist([x_lower, x_upper], color=['b', 'r'])
```